# remove single character from sentence

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following table and data:

- 1) i want to show only the last part of sentence.
- 2) remove any single character from end of sentence.
- 3) remove and special charachter like -,#,?,_ from end of words

> ```
> create table t1 (id number(9) , words varchar2(20));
> insert into t1 values(1,'hello UK');
> insert into t1 values(2,'hello Eypt');
> insert into t1 values(3,'hello ALL');
> insert into t1 values(4,'hello I');
> insert into t1 values(5,'hello USA');
> insert into t1 values(6,'hello #');
> insert into t1 values(7,'hello #');
> insert into t1 values(8,'hello A');
> insert into t1 values(9,'hello 20');
> insert into t1 values(10,'hello 2-2-2010');
> ```

i have used this

```
 select REGEXP_SUBSTR(words,'\S+$)from t1;
```

expected results

> ```
> id    word 
> 1     UK
> 2    EGYPT
> 3     ALL
> 5    USA
> 9     20
> 10    2-2-2010
> ```

Comment: Please upvote useful answers, we like rep points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL version

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX('hello UK', ' ', -1) as word WHERE LENGHT(word) > 1
```

OracleDB version (The one you must use)

```
SELECT id, SUBSTR('hello UK', INSTR('hello UK', ' ')) as word WHERE LENGHT(word) > 1
```

will return in both cases   {id} : UK

Don't forget to replace 'hello UK' with the good column name :)

[HERE](http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-apps-l/how-to-use-substring_index-402015) is the explanation for SUBSTR used with INSTR

Good luck :)

Comment: how can i remove the single charcater from the end of sentence or special character

Comment: That's what the  'WHERE LENGHT(word) > 1' is for! Anything string that is not bigger than 1 will not return as a result (as you show in your expected results)

Comment: Indeed we remove the result that has only one or less character, not the character itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Read your database manual, they all have functions that do string manipulation and they all depend on the application for their syntax. `SUBSTRING(words, 7, DATALENGTH(word) -7)` would work in SQL Server.

Comment: ok how can i remove the character like # from the end of sentence